# Widening a curve while maintaining location of maxima

Tags: probability

**Question:**
I have a function $d(x)$, which has the form
$$
d(x) = \frac{1}{r(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty r(t)dt}
$$
where $r(x)$ is another function that could be anything. I want to "widen" this formula while maintaining the local maxima in the same x-values. So maintaining the locations of the peaks while making the peaks shorter and wider.
**Context:** Given a function $f(x)$, I need to find an algorithm to approximate $f(x)$ given $n$ lines. The most obvious solution is putting n+1 points equidistantly and linearly interpolating between the points. This is not optimal. Instead, I want to focus more on points where the curvature is more extreme to get more detail where it matters. For that, I made function $d(x)$ where $r(x)$ is the radius of curvature of $f(x)$ at point $x$. I want to treat this function as the distribution of points (The weird integral is just to ensure that the total area under the curve is equal to one, making it a valid probability model). Here are $f(x)$ (red) and $d(x)$ (green) graphed on Desmos. [Desmos Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMoZm.png) (I can't embed images yet, so there is a link). As can be seen on the graph, $d(x)$ works in the sense that its peaks are in areas of greater curvature, but the problem is that it is *too* focused. The equation drops to zero too quickly, and while I don't want many points in places of lower curvature, I still want *some* detail.
**What I have already Tried:** I have tried replacing all instances of $x$ in $d(x)$ with $x/b$ where $b$ is some constant. This doesn't work because widening the entire function moves the peaks of $d(x)$ away from the areas of higher curvature of $f(x)$. It looks fine when those peaks are close to the origin, but if that's not the case, then it doesn't work.  Any help with solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Try $a \sqrt[n]{d(x)}$ for suitable constants $a,n>0$. The $n$th root has the property to make small numbers larger but large numbers smaller. With the constant $a$ you can readjust the value of the maxima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion:

Maybe you are interested in [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of $f$. For example with a gaussian $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

So you would instead take $D(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty d(t)e^{-(x-t)^2}\mathrm{d}t$.

It might move the maxima a little, but if the peaks are symmetric they won't move that much.